# How "relatively safe" is the data which was salvaged from corrupted MySQL InnoDB database?

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery

I encountered the corruption like the following.

```
150208 14:27:52  InnoDB: Error: page 443375 log sequence number 8941 870477908
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 5968 4126168076.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
```

However, fortunately, I was able to dump and restore all of the tables by using "innodb_force_recovery = 1" option. The official document says that I am "relatively safe" because the option value is less than 3. ...However, how safe is it?

> If you are able to dump your tables with an innodb_force_recovery
>   value of 3 or less, then you are **relatively safe** that only some data
>   on corrupt individual pages is lost.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

What kind of "data loss" should I assume in this case?